# How can I clone 1 Million images website?

Tags: images

I want to clone a website and upload it on my own that has 1 million images with descriptions. Descriptions need to be attached to a photo, with database possibly.

For example: https://www.freepik.com/photos/animals

I also need to update it every time a new image comes out. I tried a httrack, and it's working, but I can't figure out how to update new images with automated way.

What's the smartest way to do that?